# how to include the parameter name as the name of a column in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that looks something like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRS_Get] 
@Year Varchar(20),
@Month Varchar(20)


AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Paramdate datetime; 
DECLARE @ParamYear varchar(4);
DECLARE @ParamMonth varchar(2); 
DECLARE @Concatt varchar(10);
SET     @ParamYear = @Year;
SET     @ParamMonth = @Month;
SET     @Concatt = @ParamMonth + '-' + '01' + '-' + @ParamYear;
SET     @Paramdate = CONVERT(datetime, @Concatt);

SELECT Item
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH]  = month(@ParamDate) THEN Sales END) AS month(@ParamDate)
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN  [MONTH] = month(@ParamDate) - 1 THEN Sales END) AS month(@ParamDate) - 1,
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN  [MONTH] = month(@ParamDate) THEN Sales END) - SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = month(@ParamDate) - 1 THEN Sales END) AS  month(@ParamDate) - month(@ParamDate) - 1
FROM ABC
GROUP BY Item
```

In the above query , the part after the **AS** causes the error.
I want to use the parameter name as the name of the column , but it gives me an error. Is there a way I can use 
the parameter name as the name of the month ?

Comment: string come after "AS" causes. try to cast or converT the value.

Comment: take look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727387/sql-server-variable-columns-name

Comment: I think you'll need to use dynamic SQL to build your `AS` strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that by building the select statement as a string and then executing it using the [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) command.

So you'd get something like this:

```
declare @month0 varchar(2) = cast(month(@paramdate) as varchar(2));
declare @month1 varchar(2) = cast((month(@ParamDate) - 1) as varchar(2));
declare @month2 varchar(2) =
    cast((month(@ParamDate) - month(@ParamDate) - 1) as varchar(2));

declare s nvarchar(1024) =
  'SELECT Item
       , SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH]  = month(@d) THEN Sales END)
         AS ''' + @month0 +
   ''' , SUM(CASE WHEN  [MONTH] = month(@d) - 1 THEN Sales END)
         AS ''' + @month1 +
   ''' , SUM(CASE WHEN  [MONTH] = month(@d) THEN Sales END) -
         SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = month(@d) - 1 THEN Sales END)
         AS ''' + @month2 +
   ''' FROM ABC GROUP BY Item';

EXEC sp_executesql @s, N'@d DATETIME', @ParamDate;
```

Comment: With the above approach, I think I need to include all the declare statements too within EXECUTE command , after I do that , I get an error saying "Must declare the scalar variable "@Year" and similar message for @Month which are my stored procedure parameters. I dont think I can include them in EXEC ..

Comment: I'm updating my answer. As it turns out, you can't use `EXEC` with parameters, you have to use `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Updated... now with `sp_executesql` and a `datetime` parameter.