# Data Adapter with SELECT and WHERE clause

Tags: c#, winforms

I am only trying to look for In registration passed as parameter by the user, but it does not return anything or is not filling the DataGridView.

What can I be doing wrong ?

```
public void getLikeConta(string parametroWhere, string parametroCondicao, DataGridView dataGrid)
{

    var query = "SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador FROM GSCUsuarios WHERE @parametroWhere = @parametroCondicao";

    SqlConnection con = BancoDados.Criarconexao();

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parametroWhere", parametroWhere);
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parametroCondicao", parametroCondicao);

    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGrid.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    commandBuilder.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Where is the call of the method is passed the parameters

```
private void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Classes.Contas conta = new Classes.Contas();
    switch (cboFiltro.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            conta.getLikeConta("nome", txtBusca.Text, gridConsultaUsuario);
            configuraDataGridView();
            //gridConsultaUsuario.DataSource = conta.getContas("nome", txtBusca.Text).Tables[0];
            break;

        case 1:
            conta.getLikeConta(txtBusca.Text, "usuario", gridConsultaUsuario);
            //gridConsultaUsuario.DataSource = conta.getContas("usuario", txtBusca.Text).Tables[0];
            break;

        case 2:
            conta.getLikeConta(txtBusca.Text, "setor", gridConsultaUsuario);
            break;
        case 3:
            conta.getLikeConta(txtBusca.Text, "cargo", gridConsultaUsuario);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: what would be the expected `where condition`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can use Field name as parameter, you must write the field name in query, like that:

```
public void getLikeConta(string parametroWhere, string parametroCondicao, DataGridView dataGrid)
{
    var query = string.Format("SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador FROM GSCUsuarios WHERE {0} = @parametroCondicao", parametroWhere);

    SqlConnection con = BancoDados.Criarconexao();

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parametroCondicao", parametroCondicao);

    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGrid.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    commandBuilder.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

You can try execute this in SQL Server, the first query will work, but will bringh 0 rows, but the second query, will have data.

```
declare @parametroWhere nvarchar(max), @parametroCondicao nvarchar(max)
set @parametroWhere=N'nome'
set @parametroCondicao=N'some value that exist in db'
--first query
SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador FROM GSCUsuarios WHERE @parametroWhere = @parametroCondicao

--second query
SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador FROM GSCUsuarios WHERE nome = @parametroCondicao
```

Comment: Fixed thanks for the sugestion, but still not returning anything or not this filling the DataGridView

Comment: Do you have data in database? (você tem dados no banco de dados)?
Whats is the value of variable parametroWhere and parametroCondicao?

Comment: Yes , I ran the query and it returned me you were looking for , edited the issue with the method call getLikeConta

Comment: @Gabriel.S What is the value from parametroWhere and parametroCondicao variables?

Comment: So it depends on what the User type , edited the question to be easier to understand

Comment: @Gabriel.S I fixed my answer

Comment: Oh , perfect .. it worked. Thank you very much for your help.
If it is not asking too much , you tell me why does not work like doing? It would not be the same thing practically ?

Comment: @Gabriel.S You can see the why you can do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727387/sql-server-variable-columns-name/2727412#2727412