# Dynamic column names SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a query in such a way that column names change based on a variable.

I've tried doing something like

```
SELECT 1 AS (CASE WHEN ${x} >= 0 THEN `name1` ELSE `name2` END)
```

or

```
DEFINE MACRO c_name (CASE WHEN ${x} >= 0 THEN `name1` ELSE `name2` END)
SELECT 1 AS $c_name
```

How can I change the name of a column depending on a variable? The script should be able to run on MySQL, PostgreSQL, or some engine similar to those. The script should also not contain any "ALTER" Statements

Comment: Does it have to be "pure" SQL or do you use some programming language to build your query and run it?

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727387/sql-server-variable-columns-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql field name from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428761/mysql-field-name-from-variable)

Comment: @Nic3500 yes, sadly it has to be pure sql

Comment: This cannot be done in pure SQL. SQL is not a procedural language with variables. You'll have to embed your SQL in a script or program that constructs the second statement based on the result of the first.