# Variable as Column Name SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to know, if exist a way to create a CURSOR with a variable column names

Example:

I have this table:

[image: Result Table]

Translation image for `text`

```
ID | TEST1 | TEST2 | TEST3
7      1       3       1
8      2       3       4
9      3       4       5
10     3       3       1
11     2       3       4
12     3       4       5
13     1       3       1
14     2       3       4
15     3       4       5
```

SQL Code:

```
DECLARE
   @count int,
   @columnX varchar(5),
   @aux2previous int,
   @aux2 int,
   @aux1 int,
   @columnXResult int,
   @id int;

SET @aux2previous = 0;
SET @count = 1;

SET @columnX = 'test' + count;
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ID, @columnX FROM table

OPEN cursor1 

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @id,@columnXResult

...

SET @aux1 = @columnXResult+ @aux2previous
SET @aux2 = @aux2previous + 1                               
SET @string = 'SXW_'+@columnX+'_'+@aux1+'<>'+@aux2

INSERT INTO tblAuxiliary VALUES(@aux1,@aux2,@string)

SET @count = @count + 1;
SET @aux2previous = @aux2

...
```

[image: Result Table Auxiliary (what i need)]

Translation image for `text`

Foreach row in my first table i have a new row here:

for column Test1

```
AUX1 | AUX2 | STRING
 1      1      SXW_Test1_1<>1
 3      2      SXW_Test1_3<>2
```

for column Test2

```
AUX1 | AUX2 | STRING
 3      1      SXW_Test2_3<>1
 6      4      SXW_Test2_6<>4
```

for column Test3

```
AUX1 | AUX2 | STRING
 1      1      SXW_Test3_1<>1
 5      2      SXW_Test3_5<>2
```

when i do with @columnX

`SELECT ID, @columnX FROM table`

i got this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test1' to data type int

I see something like `@sql = 'select '+@columnX ...,` but i need to exec it and i can't do this with cursor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server variable columns name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727387/sql-server-variable-columns-name)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184725/discussion-on-question-by-leooso-variable-as-column-name-sql-server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is example how use dynamic sql and cursor:

```
create table test (
  t1 int not null,
  t2 varchar(10) not null
)

declare @query varchar(1000)

select @query = '
   declare @column int

   declare query cursor for
     select t'+cast(1 as varchar(1))+' from test

    open query
    fetch next from query into @column
    while(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    begin
       select @column

     fetch next from query into @column
    end
    close query
    deallocate query
'
exec (@query)
```

Comment: that's what I was waiting for... Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to create a cursor with variable column names unless you use dynamic SQL: you build up a string of SQL code and use EXEC sp_executesql to run it. It's messy and difficult to get right, but you can do it with some trial and error (preferably on a development system, not in production).

FWIW, I think some of the comments above a being a little harsh because they've forgotten what it's like to start out in their field: you're doing fine. Cursors *are* often misused by web developers who think procedurally instead of "set based", but I still use them occasionally where they make sense (or are just easier). If you want, you can post a new question with more details about what you're trying to accomplish and ask "how can I get rid of this cursor". But if the performance with the cursor is okay, don't worry about it.

HTH!

Comment: i think that i post every details that i can, so how can i do dynamic sql, i already tried `@sql = 'declare cursor1 cursor for.....'` and exec it, but i got an error, something like 'cant convert string to int'

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ID INT,test1 INT,test2 INT,test3 INT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(7,1,3,1),(8,2,3,4),(9,3,4,5),(10,3,3,1),
(11,2,3,4),(12,3,4,5),(13,1,3,1),(14,2,3,4),
(15,3,4,5)

SELECT top 2
t.test1 AUX1,(t.test1+T.prev_test1) AUX2,concat('SXW_Test1_',t.test1,'<>',(t.test1+T.prev_test1)) as string FROM 
(
SELECT test1,
LAG(test1,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ID) prev_test1
 FROM @table
) t

union all

SELECT top 2
t.test2 AUX1,(t.test2+T.prev_test2) AUX2,concat('SXW_Test2_',t.test2,'<>',(t.test2+T.prev_test2)) as string FROM 
(
SELECT test2,
LAG(test2,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ID) prev_test2
 FROM @table
) t

union all

SELECT top 2
t.test3 AUX1,(t.test3+T.prev_test3) AUX2,concat('SXW_test3_',t.test3,'<>',(t.test3+T.prev_test3)) as string FROM 
(
SELECT test3,
LAG(test3,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ID) prev_test3
 FROM @table
) t
```

[image]

Comment: tested here, but it was differents results that i want

Comment: the first and second output is correct, but the rest is different