# Finding average ,minumum,maximum while column names stored in temp variables in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have one table whcih is valuedata having multiple columns as `a,b,c,d,e,f`
I want to take `min`,`max`,`avg` for some columns not all which comes form inputs params from stored procedure.
my problems is when I find `avg(@column1)` it giving me output as a not values of that column so how do I solve this

```
--[MinMaxAvg_test]  'A,b,c'

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MinMaxAvg_test]
    @Parameters varchar(Max)

    AS  
    BEGIN

    Declare @ParaCount int
    declare @Para varchar(10)

    Declare @SelectedParametr_Table table(ID int identity(1,1), Parameter varchar(20))
    Insert into @SelectedParametr_Table SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@Parameters, ',')

     set @ParaCount=1
        While(@ParaCount <=(Select count(Parameter) from @SelectedParametr_Table))
            Begin
        set @Para=null
         select @Para=Parameter from @SelectedParametr_Table where id=@ParaCount

        Select top(1) min(@Para) as MIN,max(@Para) As MAX,avg(@Para) as AVG from VALUEDATA

      set @ParaCount=@ParaCount+1

      end
        set @ParaCount=1

    END
```

```
Output of this I am getting as follows :
             MIN   MAX  AVG
              A     A    A

             MIN   MAX  AVG
              B     B    B 

             MIN   MAX  AVG
              C     C    C
```

I want values for this columns how to do this can any one tell me

Comment: Object names (like tables, columns, etc.) cannot be referenced with a variable. You need to use Dynamic SQL for that. So, build a string with the hard-coded SQL and concatenate whatever the `@Para` is holding. Beware of SQL injection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727387/sql-server-variable-columns-name

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic query such as:

```
set @vQuery as nvarchar(max) = 'Select top(1) min('+@Para+') as MIN,max(+'@Para'+) As MAX,avg('+@Para+') as AVG from VALUEDATA'

exec (@vQuery)
```

As a best practice, I would recommend to change the while cycle to a cursor.