# IF EXISTS does not return correct result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to check if a column in my sql table has null values and to print 'Yes'/'No'

```
DECLARE @columnName nvarchar(50)

SET @columnName = 'City'

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rf.Country WHERE @columnName IS NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Yes'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No'
END
```

This query returns 'No' when I know for sure that there are null values in this column. I see that it is not allowed to use @var in WHERE statement but I need a way to loop through all columns in a table and to print result for each column if it contains NULL values.

Comment: You can't use variables for column names like that. Please see [SQL Server variable columns name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727387/sql-server-variable-columns-name) for a workaround.

Comment: Careful, all the examples in that link, from @AndrewMorton, are open to injection attacks.

Comment: You can get all the column names in a table: [How can I get column names from a table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server), and you can quote those names to use them in dynamic SQL with [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **safely** inject the value into a dynamic query, and then execute that:

```sql
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname; --synonym for nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
SET @ColumnName = N'City';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rf.Country WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' IS NULL)' + @CRLF +
           N'    PRINT N''Yes'';' + @CRLF +
           N'ELSE' + @CRLF +
           N'    PRINT N''No'';';

--PRINT @SQL;  --Your debugging friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked just fine. I will need to understand the whole thing though (I am new to SQL). For example, can you please explain to me why do you write @CRLF? Also, Can I put this whole query in a while loop and go through every column?

Comment: [Why I define my Carriage Returns and Line Breaks as variables in Dynamic SQL](https://wp.larnu.uk/why-i-declare-my-carriage-returns-and-line-breaks-in-dynamic-sql/) @Yana. Putting it a loop seems like an odd idea though, all this is doing is printing `N'Yes'` or `N'No'`; it's not giving any meaning information.

Comment: Thank you for the link. As for the loop, with Python I can easily check if the columns of a table have null values. I have no idea how to do this easily with SQL. And I don't want to do it hardcoded by checking each column separately.

Comment: So what do you want to do with that, @Yana? just printing `N'Yes'` or `N'No'` would tell you anything about what columns do (and don't) have `NULL` values. If you simply want a count of `NULL` values, there are plenty of examples out there. Such as this [shameless self promotion](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/count-non-null-rows-and-get-definition) (just need to count the `NULL` values instead of the `NOT NULL` values).

Comment: Well, I am at the beginning of exploring a big database. I need to look for columns which can be useful for filtering, JOINs and in the (hopefully) near future use this data in ML models. Anyway, I need to know which columns have Nulls in order to look more closely at them and see if there are some issues. Thank you for the second link, too. I believe it will be very useful too.

Comment: Doing this operation against every column moves the goal posts a little bit, @Yana , so you would probably be better off with a new question, especially as you omitted that requirement from your question initially. You'll need to explain what the dataset you're expecting is though, as (like I mentioned) just printing `N'Yes'` or `N'No'` wouldn't tell you anything.

Comment: I will take into consideration your comments and will post a new question when I clear my objective about this topic more. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is not checking the column values in the table.  It is just checking the constant -- and `@columnName IS NULL` always evaluates to false because `@columnName` has a value.

You would need to use dynamic SQL.  Perhaps:

```
DECLARE @columnName nvarchar(50)

SET @columnName = 'City';

SET @SQL = '
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rf.Country WHERE @columnName IS NULL)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as flag
';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@columnName', @columnName)

DECLARE @flag INT;

EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL,
                   N'@flag int OUTPUT',
                   @flag=@flag OUTPUT;

IF @flag = 1
    PRINT 'Yes';
ELSE
    PRINT 'No';
```

In general, I would discourage you from writing code where you need to pass column names around like this.  That usually indicates a problem with the data model.  I should say "usually".  Under some circumstances, this can be convenient.

Comment: The idea is that I want to be able to loop through all columns and to check if they contain 'NULL' values. I will edit this in my description.

Comment: @Yana . . . This code is perfectly safe if you are looping through column names coming from the system tables.  I do note that it does not handle column names with non-standard identifier characters, but that didn't seem to be part of your question, which was why your code is not working.