# SQL Server : select query with dynamic column selection in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2017

Users want to have an option to control which columns are present in the final report.

One option is to get a list of fields requested. Is it possible in SQL Server to write a query like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727387/sql-server-variable-columns-name)? But I need to select a list of values, not just a single variable.

My plan is to get a parameter's list from a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT ('Table2.', name) AS ColumnName 
FROM 
    sys.columns 
WHERE 
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('Table1')
```

The user would select columns they need this time, and then I want to use parameter list somehow like that:

```
SELECT @ColumnName FROM Table2
```

Of course it's not working this way...

Is there an option to get result that I want?

Comment: `exec sp_executesql ...`

Comment: You need to bear in mind that SSRS expects a dataset with the same columns each time, so the name names and datatypes. The only way to do it, as far as I know, would be to pivot the columns in your query then use a matrix to pivot them back again. If that makes no sense, let me know and I will post an example

Comment: Example would be nice, thanks. As far as i can see now, there's no easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check 'allow multiple values' for your parameter

In hide/show expression of the visibility of the column, put:

```
=IIF(instr(join(Parameters!ParamName.label,","),"NameColumn_to_filter")>0,false,true)
```